# "Converting" Double to Int

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a function that calculates change when given an amount of coins. It has worked great except when I actually want the input to be a Double rather than Int.

This is my code

```
coins::[Int]
coins = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
change::Int->[Int]->[Int]
change n [] = []
change n coins
         | n == 0 = []
         | n >= firstcoin = firstcoin:change (n-firstcoin) coins  
         | otherwise = change n (tail coins)
         where firstcoin = head coins
```

This works nice and all, but when I try changing the code to:

```
change::Double->[Int]->[Int]
         | (n*100) == 0 = []
         | (n*100) >= firstcoin = firstcoin:change (n-firstcoin) coins
         | otherwise = change n (tail coins)
         where firstcoin = head coins
```

The following happens:

```
  [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( coin.hs, interpreted )

  coin.hs:7:27:
  Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
  In the second argument of ‘(>=)’, namely ‘firstcoin’
  In the expression: (n * 100) >= firstcoin

  coin.hs:7:59:
  Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
  In the second argument of ‘(-)’, namely ‘firstcoin’
  In the first argument of ‘change’, namely ‘(n - firstcoin)’
  Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Is this like using "/" where I have to use fromIntegral beforehand? If so, how does that translate here?

*A little side question: how can I make the list of coins written here "embedded" into the function so that the signature would look like:

```
change::Int->[Int]
```

(in other words, I don't want to explicitly write in the list for it to work. Would I need to change my whole code?)

Comment: One of the first rules of dealing with currency is to not use floating-point values to represent amounts of money.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: Floating-point values are just approximations of real numbers. You wouldn't be making change for some fuzzy fraction of a dollar; you make change for an exact integer number of cents.

Comment: Consider this sum: `sum (replicate 10 0.01)`

Comment: (Corollary: consider @chepner 's example in light of your program: `sum (replicate 10 0.01) - 0.1 == 0`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This time I think you are looking for [`round`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round). Also, I think you really do want a new function `changeDouble` here, not to modify `change`. This will solve your `Double` problem nicely and presents the simpler signature `changeDouble :: Double -> [Int]`.

```
changeDouble :: Double -> [Int]
changeDouble n = change (round (100 * n)) coins
```

The problem with mixing `Double` and `Int` is indeed the same as you would encounter via use of `/` on `Int`s.

---

As a side note, even if your proposed updated code to `change` were to compile, note that the recursive call would need to be updated to pass in `n - (fromIntegral firstCoin) / 10` instead of just `n - firstCoin`.

Comment: I renamed my original function to    changeHelp and your suggestion to    change, now it works great! Thank you.